# How to get Network Analyst to find nearest facility on globe?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, network-analyst

Currently, the nearest facility matrix results stay within the confines of the GCS84 projection, so the route from Los Angles to Japan travels EAST not WEST. How can I change the settings to permit it to solve on a orthographic world?

Answer (score 1):

Network analyst will solve the graph that is provided to it. So you can either use a projection that is not "cut" at the opposite of a prime meridian, or create virtual East-West links with a zero length to make sure that the connections exist when you cross the day line.